# React Testing Library: Objects are not valid as a React child

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I am trying to write test using jest and I hit this error

```
Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
        in td (created by TableCell)
        in TableCell (created by DataTable)
        in tr (created by TableExpandRow)
        in TableExpandRow (created by DataTable)
        in tbody (created by TableBody)
        in TableBody (created by DataTable)
        in table (created by Table)
        in Table (created by DataTable)
        in div (created by DataTable)
        in div (created by TableContainer)
        in TableContainer (created by DataTable)
        in div (created by DataTable)
        in DataTable
        in Unknown
        in Unknown (created by EnhancedDataTable)
        in EnhancedDataTable (created by MyPage)
        in div (created by MyPage)
        in MyPage


  27 | 
  28 |     it('renders', () => {
> 29 |         const { container } = render(<MyPage />);
```

MyPage is a functional component which returns

```
<React.Fragment>
    <MyHeader title={'Page Header'} />
    <div className="page-content">
        <EnhancedDataTable
            actions={actions}
            rowActions={rowActions}
            headers={rowHeaders}
            rowDetail={rowDetail}
            rows={rowsData}
            className='my-table'
        />
    </div>
</React.Fragment>
```

What am i missing here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to render an object (promise) as a child. From your code it's hard to know where, but, assuming that your table works like rc-components table, it could be something like this:

Lets say I have an array and want to render it to a table

```js
const arr = [
  {
    company: 'XYZ',
    owner: {
      name: 'Julius'
    }
  }
]
```

Now, i want to render it in a table with columns: | company | owner |, so I create a headers array:

```js
const arr = [
  {
    dataIndex: 'company'
  },
  {
    dataIndex: 'owner'
  }
]
```

Now, this wont work, because my table will try to render the object `{name: 'Julius'}`, and objects are not valid as react children.

The fix would be changing my headers to something like:

```js
const arr = [
  {
    dataIndex: 'company'
  },
  {
    dataIndex: ['owner', 'name']
  }
]
```

Now it should work, because the colum will be `row['owner']['name']`, a string.

Without more code, it's hard to tell exactly where the problem is, but hopefully the exemple gave you an idea o what react means with that error. all i know is that the error is somewhere in the cells of your table, since the stack shows `in Unknown (created by EnhancedDataTable)` and the last (or first, i guess) item is a `td`, a common element for table data.

Comment: You should check `rowsData`, since it's most likely the only thing in your table that renders something directly and should be rendered as a td.

Comment: Silly me, You are right! I was using `const [rowsData, setRowsData] = useState(null);` instead of  `const [rowsData, setRowsData] = useState([]);`. After changing null ==> [], the test passed

Comment: Oops Sorry, I dint realize in a hurry that i had commented test code which led to passed tests. The issue still persists though.

Comment: It should still be an issue with the data, my guess is that you are loading it from an external api of sorts, but aren't awaiting the return, something like: `setRowsData(api.get('/data'))` when it should be `setRowsData(await api.get('/data'))`. Either that or an object in rows has a promise inside it. both should be easy to spot by changin the `rows={rowsData}` to `rows={[]}` and putting a `console.log(rowsData)` right before the return statement of `MyPage`

Comment: You could also post more of the code from `MyPage`, if it is what I it is, the `headers` and anything to do with rows data should help. Also the type you expect to receive inside rows data.